# Give the smallest positive value of $x$ for which $\tan x$ is undefined.

Tags: trigonometry

Give the smallest positive value of  $x$ for which $\tan x$ is undefined. An answer and explanation on how to solve would be great.

Comment: On which domain is $\tan(x)$ defined?

Comment: An explanation will depend on what you know about trigonometry. Please add context to your Question.

Comment: Step 1: draw a graph. Step 2: look at graph. Step 3: ......

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$1>$ What is the definition of $\tan(x)$ ?

$2>$ Is dividing by $0$ defined?